# Firebird SQL Fail to open fdb file

Tags: macos, firebird2.5

I'm trying to access to fdb database (created with firebird 1.5) with the command:

```
connect "/Users/myuser/Desktop/DB.FDB";
```

The console tell me:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
file /Users/myuser/Desktop/DB.FDB is not a valid database
```

I use firebird 2.5 for OS X
Tried also firebird 1.5 for windows but same result.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Where does this `DB.FDB` come from? The error indicates that it isn't a Firebird database (which in some cases might mean it comes from a different platform, and needs to be backed up on one system and restored on the other system).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it come from firebird 1.5

Comment: Did it come from Windows? If so: backup and restore.